# Pandas groupby city and month and fill in missing months

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with several cities with multiple values for every month. I need to group those values by city and month, filling missing months with NA.

Grouping by city and month works:

```
self.probes[['city', 'date', 'value']].groupby(['city',pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M')])

| Munich   | 2018-06 | values... |
| Munich   | 2018-08 | values... |
| Munich   | 2018-09 | values... |
| New York | 2018-06 | values... |
| New York | 2018-07 | values... |
```

But I can't manage to include missing months.

```
| Munich   | 2018-06 | values... |
| Munich   |*2018-07*| NA instead of values |
| Munich   | 2018-08 | values... |
| Munich   | 2018-09 | values... |
| New York | 2018-06 | values... |
| New York | 2018-07 | values... |
```

Comment: In final DataFrame need same number of months for each group? So from input data also is necessary add `| New York | 2018-08 | values... |` ?

Comment: No, the number of months is different per city, so e.g. Amsterdam might only have data starting from 2018-09. The months of one city just have to be continuous.

Comment: I don't see the Question very readable...  can it be more explicit & detailed? like what DataFrame really looks like and what is desired that will make it more clear.

Comment: @pygo Could you give me a hint on how to generate those tables? Writing them by hand is tedious...

Comment: @KarlBirkkar,  Jezrael also given nice answer i believe thats what you want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you need add some aggregate function like `sum` first:

```
print (probes)
       city        date  value
0    Munich  2018-06-01      4
1    Munich  2018-08-01      1
2    Munich  2018-08-03      5
3    Munich  2018-09-01      1
4  New York  2018-06-01      1
5  New York  2018-07-01      2

probes['date'] = pd.to_datetime(probes['date'])
s = probes.groupby(['city',pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M')])['value'].sum()
print (s)
city      date      
Munich    2018-06-30    4
          2018-08-31    6
          2018-09-30    1
New York  2018-06-30    1
          2018-07-31    2
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

And then use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `city` with [`asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html), [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) is necessary for `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df1 = (s.reset_index(level=0)
        .groupby('city')['value']
        .apply(lambda x: x.asfreq('M'))
        .reset_index())
print (df1)
       city       date  value
0    Munich 2018-06-30    4.0
1    Munich 2018-07-31    NaN
2    Munich 2018-08-31    6.0
3    Munich 2018-09-30    1.0
4  New York 2018-06-30    1.0
5  New York 2018-07-31    2.0
```

Also is possible use `MS` for start of month:

```
probes['date'] = pd.to_datetime(probes['date'])
s = probes.groupby(['city',pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='MS')])['value'].sum()

df1 = (s.reset_index(level=0)
        .groupby('city')['value']
        .apply(lambda x: x.asfreq('MS'))
        .reset_index()
        )
print (df1)
       city       date  value
0    Munich 2018-06-01    4.0
1    Munich 2018-07-01    NaN
2    Munich 2018-08-01    6.0
3    Munich 2018-09-01    1.0
4  New York 2018-06-01    1.0
5  New York 2018-07-01    2.0
```

Comment: Thank you! Only grouping by city first before resampling was the hint I needed :) This is what made it work now: `probes[['city','date', 'value1', 'value2']].set_index('date')\
.groupby('city')\
.resample('M')\
.apply(lambda x: calculate(x.value1, x.value2))
`

Comment: @KarlBirkkar, Jezrael is always been like a mentor  for pandas solution :)

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand, why need `sum()` in this case?

Comment: @ahbon - For unique combinations `city` and `pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='MS')`

Comment: If my data only has one `value` for each month, does it necessary?

Comment: @ahbon - No, then not. If raise error, need aggregate `sum`

Comment: If I have others columns, say, `a, b, c, d, ...`, what I should add, I find in `df1`, those are missing.

Comment: You mean `['value']` in `s`, no, it doesn't work out. I raise another question, please check out if you have time. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57622629/grouby-and-fill-missing-months-in-multiple-columns-data-frame-in-python