# Grouby and fill missing months in multiple columns data frame in Python

Tags: python, pandas

For a data frame like this, how could I group by `id` and fill missing months while keep `price` of missing months as `na`, the expected date range is from `2015/1/1` to `2019/8/1`.

```
   city district     id  price       date
0    hz       xs  20101    1.5   2019/8/1
1    hz       xs  20101   50.0   2019/7/1
2    hz       xs  20101    2.0   2019/6/1
3    hz       xs  20101    2.2   2019/5/1
4    hz       sn  20101    2.2   2019/4/1
5    hz       sn  20102    2.1  2018/10/1
6    hz       sn  20102   70.0   2019/3/1
7    hz       sn  20102    2.2   2019/2/1
8    hz       sn  20102    nan   2019/1/1
9    hz       sn  20102    2.0  2018/12/1
10   hz       sn  20102    2.2  2018/11/1
11   xz       pd  20103    2.9   2015/7/1
12   xz       pd  20103    2.0   2015/8/1
13   xz       pd  20103    2.5   2015/9/1
14   xz       pd  20103    3.0  2015/10/1
15   xz       pd  20103   35.0  2015/11/1
16   xz       pd  20103    3.2  2015/12/1
17   xz       pd  20103    3.1   2016/1/1
18   xz       pd  20103    nan   2016/2/1
19   xz       pd  20103    nan   2016/3/1
20   xz       pd  20103    nan   2016/4/1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

In real data is necessary unique values per columns `city`,`district`,`id`, `date`:

```
df = df.groupby(['city','district','id', 'date'], as_index=False)['price'].sum()
```

If need grouping by `id` column:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2015-01-01','2019-08-01', freq='MS')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df1 = (df.set_index('date')
         .groupby('id')
         .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(rng))
         .rename_axis(('id','date'))
         .drop('id', axis=1)
         .reset_index()
        )
print (df1)

        id       date city district  price
0    20101 2015-01-01  NaN      NaN    NaN
1    20101 2015-02-01  NaN      NaN    NaN
2    20101 2015-03-01  NaN      NaN    NaN
3    20101 2015-04-01  NaN      NaN    NaN
4    20101 2015-05-01  NaN      NaN    NaN
..     ...        ...  ...      ...    ...
163  20103 2019-04-01  NaN      NaN    NaN
164  20103 2019-05-01  NaN      NaN    NaN
165  20103 2019-06-01  NaN      NaN    NaN
166  20103 2019-07-01  NaN      NaN    NaN
167  20103 2019-08-01  NaN      NaN    NaN

[168 rows x 5 columns]
```

Also if need grouping by more columns:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2015-01-01','2019-08-01', freq='MS')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df2 = (df.set_index('date')
         .groupby(['city','district','id'])['price']
         .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(rng, fill_value=0))
         .rename_axis(('city','district','id','date'))
         .reset_index()
        )
print (df2)

    city district     id       date  price
0     hz       sn  20101 2015-01-01    0.0
1     hz       sn  20101 2015-02-01    0.0
2     hz       sn  20101 2015-03-01    0.0
3     hz       sn  20101 2015-04-01    0.0
4     hz       sn  20101 2015-05-01    0.0
..   ...      ...    ...        ...    ...
219   xz       pd  20103 2019-04-01    0.0
220   xz       pd  20103 2019-05-01    0.0
221   xz       pd  20103 2019-06-01    0.0
222   xz       pd  20103 2019-07-01    0.0
223   xz       pd  20103 2019-08-01    0.0

[224 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: Is it possible to keep `city, district` value for missing months? Maybe I should grouby with those 3 columns.

Comment: it's weird, i get `raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis") ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`, for my real data.

Comment: @ahbon - ya, it is exactly reason for aggregate, e.g. by  `sum`. Give me some time.

Comment: @ahbon - Use `df = df.groupby(['city','district','id', 'date'], as_index=False)['price'].sum()` before my solution - need unique values in per columns `'city','district','id', 'date'`

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry I’m not beside of computer and will try after two hours

Comment: This worked out, could you please edit your code by adding this line.

Comment: Just find one problem, some `price`s get lost after doing all the process, do you know why this happens?

Comment: @ahbon - One idea - If aggregate `sum`, it is not reason for it?

Comment: Do you have ideas to avoid missing `price` while fill missing months?

Comment: @ahbon - Here `, fill_value=0` in `reindex` cannot be used?

Comment: Yes, I used `fill_value=0` in `reindex`, so some price value from original data are replaced by `o`.

Comment: @ahbon - So another values was removed?

Comment: Yes, that very strange, I'm considering use another method to concatenate and drop duplicates to get back `price` values you have answered in another post, it seems works.

Answer (score 0):

Using `reindex` with `MS` which is month start and [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `GroupBy`:

```
dates = pd.date_range('2015-01-01','2019-08-01', freq='MS')

new = pd.concat([
    d.set_index('date').reindex(dates).reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'date'}) for _, d in df.groupby('id')
], ignore_index=True)

new = new.ffill().bfill()
```

**Output**

```
          date city district       id  price
0   2015-01-01   hz       sn  20101.0    2.2
1   2015-02-01   hz       sn  20101.0    2.2
2   2015-03-01   hz       sn  20101.0    2.2
3   2015-04-01   hz       sn  20101.0    2.2
4   2015-05-01   hz       sn  20101.0    2.2
..         ...  ...      ...      ...    ...
163 2019-04-01   xz       pd  20103.0    3.1
164 2019-05-01   xz       pd  20103.0    3.1
165 2019-06-01   xz       pd  20103.0    3.1
166 2019-07-01   xz       pd  20103.0    3.1
167 2019-08-01   xz       pd  20103.0    3.1

[168 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: I want to add missing months from `2015-01-01 to 2019-08-01` for each `id`.

Comment: Thanks but city district and id values should be kept

Comment: Sorry, i got same error like this `raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis") ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`