# How Do I Merge Two Dataframes to Generate NaN Entries?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a large Pandas data frame, call it *df*, with aggregated monthly counts of crime incidents. For example, it looks much like:

| ID | Year_Month | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LA67890 | 2018-08 | 18791 |
| HA86759 | 2017-06 | 17645 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| LA43210 | 2017-07 | 1 |

What I want to do is fill in months with NaN that do not have an entry for each month and each ID. In other words, say LA67890 doesn't have an entry for 2018-07, then I'd like to have a row generated with that ID, Year_Month as 2018-07, and Count as NaN.

What I have tried is generating a new data frame, call it *df1*, with two columns, with months ranging from the earliest incident to the latest. For example:
|      Year_Month      |     Fill_Count|
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1991-01       |         NaN      |
|           ...        |        ..|
|2018-12| NaN|

I tried using left merge to accomplish this:

```
new_df = df1.merge(df, on='Year_Month', how='left')
```

but it did not work for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Is there an easier way to accomplish this same task?

Comment: Have you looked at pivot_table as a direction? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: Add data for missing months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343726/pandas-add-data-for-missing-months). or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53209185/pandas-groupby-city-and-month-and-fill-in-missing-months?